# running slow slide effects on android xibo

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm doing one slide and more applications using jquery effects, CSS3. When I run the application on the browser chrome, they move very fast. But why when I run the application on xibo was very slow? who can help me? thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. **Help others to help you (hint: provide some code)**
2. A cryptic question will at best win you a cryptic answer.

Performance issues are device and browser dependent. Is your chrome on a desktop? It has higher CPU/memory and likely have a 2D or 3D capability. Your Xido is built less well for such tasks.

The following might help...

```
$("#yourtag").slideDown( "fast" );
```

Source: http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/